# LINQ/Lambda expression: Join lists and find the average counts of data with the given formula

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

I have a list of 500+ **EventData** records. Model of **EventData** is as given below

```
public class EventData
{
    public int preEventId { get; set; }
    public int empNum { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Here the EventId can be 1,2,3,4 and 5 (Enum). and from this list, I want to filter the records for all weeks of the month and then calculate the avg. NB: **weekList** is the list of Mondays in the current month.

*(count of records having EventId = 1) / (count of records with EventId = 2 or 5 and empNum's with EventId = 1 (CreateDate 5 days old or newer))*

What I've done is:-

```
int calledCount = lstEventData?.Where(e => e.EventId == 1 &&
                     e.CreateDate >= weekList.ToList()[week] &&
                     e.CreateDate <= weekList.ToList()[week].AddDays(4)).Count() ?? 0;
                     

int totalCount = (lstEventData?
                    .Where(e => (e.EventCd == 2 || e.EventCd == 5) &&
                                 e.CreateDate >= weekList.ToList()[week] &&
                                 e.CreateDate <= weekList.ToList()[week].AddDays(4))
                    .GroupBy(e => e.empNum)
                    .Select(x => x.First())
                    .Count()) ?? 0;
                    
 int avgCalls = Convert.ToDecimal(calledCount) / Convert.ToDecimal(totalCount);
```

Sample SQL structure of the same:

```
SELECT * FROM CalledList c  INNER JOIN
        Events e 
        ON (c.empNum = e.empNum AND c.EventId IN(2,5) 
        AND c.CreateDate > e.CreateDate - 5
        AND c.EventId = 1
```

How can I achieve my actual goal?

Comment: You most likely don't need to call ToList() (isn't it already a list?), but definitely shouldn't do it in that way because it is happening for every iteration in the lstEventData. If you do need to call ToList(), do it once before the linq queries and reference the new variable. Better yet, since `week` is not changing, just set weekList[week] to a variable.

Comment: Can you explain what you are calculating with more detail? You have what seems to be contradictory information (e.g. what does "and `empNum's` with `EventId = 1`" mean? How can you be all weeks of the month and `CreateDate` 5 days old or newer?

Comment: Also, what is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can infer from your code and explanation, I think this is what you're after:

```cs
// first, to reduce parsing your weekList EVERY time, get a reference to your start/end dates
  var wkStart = weekList.ToList()[week];

  // This may not quite work since if your weekstart is Monday midnight, 
  // adding 4 days is Friday midnight, so 12:01 AM Friday won't fall into your range.
  // I'd recommend doing AddDays(5), and using less than (<), not less than or equal (<=)
  var wkEnd = wkStart.AddDays(5); 
  
  // using consts to avoid "magic numbers"
  const int CALLED_LIST = 1;
  const int OTHER_EVENTS = 2;

  // Then get all of the events in that period that match the EventIds you want, 
  // just so your followup queries are against a smaller set
  var events = 
    lstEventData?
    .Where(e => (
    (e.EventId == 1 && e.CreateDate >= wkStart && e.CreateDate <= wkEnd) // event ID 1 within date range
                    || e.EventId == 2 || e.EventId == 5 // or event ID 2 or 5, ingoring date range for the moment
                    ))
    // Create a lookup to split by event ID to have two separate lists to join below    
    .ToLookup(e => e.EventId == 1 ? CALLED_LIST : OTHER_EVENTS);    
    
  var calledList = events[CALLED_LIST].ToList();
  var otherEvents = events[OTHER_EVENTS].ToList();
  
  if ((calledList?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
  {
    // you need to handle empty or null to
    // avoid a DivdeByZero error below.
    return;
  }
  // by handling the null/empty above, you no longer need to handle it everywhere below;
  var joinedResults = 
    calledList.Join(otherEvents, 
      c => c.empNum,
      e => e.empNum,
      (c,e) => new {Parent = c, Child = e})
      .Where(joined => joined.Parent.CreateDate > joined.Child.CreateDate.AddDays(-5));     
  
  // From here, you'll need to figure out what average you're trying to get. 
  // I made a note in the comments that I'm unclear what average you're trying to calculate.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but ultimately what I want to get as calledCount is the count of given sample sql:
    SELECT * FROM CalledList c  INNER JOIN
      Events e 
         ON (c.empNum = e.empNum AND c.EventId IN(2,5) 
            AND c.CreateDate > e.CreateDate - 5
      AND c.EventId = 1

Comment: I see your sql which implies you're querying two different tables, but in your c#, you're querying the same list. Is that right? Is `CalledList` really just the same as `lstEventData` where EventId == 1?

Comment: Yes, CalledList is just the same as lstEventData where EventId == 1

Comment: so I think I'm closer, but I'm not quite sure where `empNum` comes into play here. Your `avgCalls` count doesn't seem to care about `empNum` Are you trying to get an average per `empNum` or just an overall average of `EventId==1` to `EventId==2|5` ?